# ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION being granted in manifest, yet always getting permission denied?

Tags: android

I'm currently trying to get the latitude and longitude of the user's current location. I have enabled the following permissions in the manifest. TargetSDK and min sdk are 23

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.name.app">


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="false" />


    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainMenu" />
    <activity
        android:name=".NeedToKnow" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SelectTopic" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayTopicInformation"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".SelectCheckList" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ViewCheckList"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".FindLocation"></activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


</manifest>
```

In order to do so I understand that I need to perform a runtime check for the permissions.  However when I perform the following I always get -1 in return. (PERMISSION_DENIED)

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
```

Is there a step I am missing when trying to access current locations?

Full code is here:

```
private String getZipcodeFromCurrentLocation() {

    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

    String zip = null;
    Location location = null;
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();

            Log.i("updated lat", String.valueOf(latitude));
            Log.i("updated lng", String.valueOf(longitude));
        }


    };

    try {
        if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == permissionCheck) {
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }

    } catch (SecurityException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return zip;

}
```

Comment: Please post your entire manifest. Also, what is your `targetSdkVersion`, and what version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: The reason for runtime checks is that the user can turn off locations entirely, or deny permission to an app that wants them.  Are either of those the case?

Comment: @CommonsWare I added the Manifest

Comment: @GabeSechan no. Maybe I am misunderstanding how to check for permissions?

Comment: You can try moving your `<uses-permission>` elements to appear before `<application>`, which is where we normally see them. Also, as I asked previously, what is your `targetSdkVersion`, and what version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: @CommnsWare TargetedSdkVersion is 23 & I'm testing on API 23

Comment: I would do as CommonsWare advised and move your permissions prior to   <application> opening tag. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If user has disabled location permission for your app in the phone's settings, then you have to request that permission. Below you'll find a sample piece of code on how to do it.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements  ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        boolean permissionGranted = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

        if(permissionGranted) {
            // {Some Code}
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 200);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 200: {
                if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // {Some Code}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also I've build a class that handles all of the above and also returns user's location. Here's the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2mkyjok6mpna2yw/GPS.java?dl=0.

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for answering a question. Please add context to your answer in addition to code.

Comment: I will have to try this solution when I get back as I need to leave soon. My question for Arnold is the check is to confirm that the user has not turned off their location services? Not that the manifest has uses-permission ?

Comment: Your Manifest file is fine, you don't need to add or delete anything (Maybe just put the permission tags before the application tags, but I'm not sure if that's a problem). You have to check first if permission has been granted by user (Not that the user has location services enabled), and then if he has granted you permission to use his location check if he has location services enabled. Just check the file that I put on the link above and you'll see that you have everything there.

Comment: Hi @arnoldplakoli Thank you for your response. Using you example I was able to figure it out. Thank you for explaining it to me. it appears the location of the `<uses-permission/>` tag does not matter as long as it is a child of the manifest tag.

Comment: Looking at your GPS class, location appears to be null and throws errors. I will look at it soon but wanted to give you a heads up :)

Comment: That's weird. Did you check if you can get location first ?  There's a method there called `canGetLocation()`. You have to check for that first otherwise it may return `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the class, but how to call the class?? I tried using GPS insgps=new GPS() but this did not work, how can I call it?!

Comment: @asmgx You can access a method of this class like this `GPS.sharedInstance(activity).method()`. The reason you can not create a new instance of this class is because its constructor is private.

Comment: @ArnoldPlakolli Am I not calling this function correctly? I keep getting `attempt to invoke virtual method ... on a null object reference` .. `if (GPS.sharedInstance(this).canGetLocation()) {
            double lat = GPS.sharedInstance(this).getLatitude();
            double lon = GPS.sharedInstance(this).getLatitude();
            Log.e(TAG, "Location: " + lat + "/"+ lon);
        }`

Comment: @Jayce Sorry for such a late response, but I haven't visited this SO post in a looong time, and also I've moved to iOS development since I've posted posted this answer. 
Anyhow, the `GPS.sharedInstance`, can never return `null`, you can see for yourself inside that class that only one instance of `GPS` object can be created and that instance never gets destroyed. Check if maybe `_locationManager` object is `null`.