# Getting permission on runtime in android

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I'm new to android, don't know what I'm doing wrong
this class get longitude and latitude and sent to another class
the code is throwing an error `onrequstpermission` please tell me what to do how to do:

> error on  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
                        switch (requestCode) {
                            case Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION:
                                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                    // All good!
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(this, "Need your location!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You cant declare a function inside of another function

Comment: You may find this talk helpful:
https://youtu.be/WGz-alwVh8A

Also, this helper library makes dealing with permissions much easier: 
https://github.com/hiqes/andele

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onRequestPermissionsResult` is a method which should be outside the current method

```
public Location getLocation(){
    //...code
      if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermissio... ) {

    // ERROR : cannot have function declaration inside another function
          public void onRequestPermissionsResult(...) {
                switch (requestCode) {//..code}
          }
}
```

**Note:** you cannot have this in a `Service` class , you need some `Activity` to ask permission

[`ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html) is implemented by `FragmentActivity` which is a parent of `AppCompatActivity` so it's not implemented by `Service` so you need to implement the runtime-permission code is some `FragmentActivity | AppCompatActivity` or you can check and show a notification (in case of no permission or probably a dialog)  and redirect user to `Activity` to proceed with permission code.

Reference:
[**Implement runtime permission**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33162451/4936904)

Comment: can you give a clean code, this application is for marshmallo

Comment: @AliAhmedSiddiqui read the updated answer , long thing short, you need to ask permission in some activity

Comment: wait let me check

Comment: error on case
 public class requst {
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
            case Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // All good!
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Need your location!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;


            }
        }
    }

Comment: @AliAhmedSiddiqui first don't post bulky code in comment, looks really ugly and it should be `requst extends AppCompatActivity` not a plain `class` , `onRequestPermissionsResult ` is a `method` needs to be `overriden` , i hope you know about `@Override` method, you need some `AppCompatActivity` , refresh the page in case you are unable to see updates  and follow instruction carefully

Comment: expected ';' at case Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;

Comment: I'll be very thankful if you can please give me a clean code :(

Comment: @AliAhmedSiddiqui seems like a compile time syntax error , kindly add **[code mentioned by this linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33162451/4936904)** in your `AppCompatActivity`, code will be the same , just use `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` instead of `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` from linked answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35187588/access-fine-location-being-granted-in-manifest-yet-always-getting-permission-de
i found this usefull :) And very very thanks to you @Pavneet_Singh

Comment: @AliAhmedSiddiqui i am glad that i could help , happy coding